# If my guitar only had one string

Tags: guitar

If the string is tuned to G and I want to play the chord progression G B C and C minor, could I somehow imply the C and C minor chord on the same string?                I am trying to learn songs on a diddley bow.I can play songs rhythmically by strumming the note in place of the chords. These notes become implied chords. I went for a long time learning songs this way and it works pretty good... I know that I could just keep strumming the C note through both the C and C minor ,but it is not as colorful. I am 50 and I don't know squat when it comes to music.            I do know that I can play both the G major and minor scales on the same string.      And that G minor scale has an Eb note in it... also C minor has a relative chord Eb major. Could I then play the Eb note to imply the C minor chord?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you could play the other notes from the chord ('chord tones') as well as the root note. (Depending on how you do this, this is sometimes called an [arpeggio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpeggio)).

So to play a C major chord, you could make up a pattern with C, E, and G.

To play a C minor chord, you could make up a pattern with C, Eb, and G.

You may be able to imply C minor simply by throwing in one Eb in among the C notes.

Comment: The chord progression belongs to the song Creep . When I play a song I try to simulate a strumming pattern and play the chords like that. I am familiar with arpeggio but that is more on the melodic side of a song . I have used tabs with arpeggio to learn a more melodic part to a song ,but it can get difficult running up and down the fret board . I will try it that way.  So maybe i can use the Eb note? It sounds close being Eb major is C minors happy...  was surprised to learn that C minor does not belong to C majors group of 6 chords on the Circle of Fifths.

Comment: I usually use voice sheet music for the melody of a song and then use the implied chords and strumming to make it more interesting and fun. Trying to learn as much as I can on  my diddley bow before I move on to my three string.

Comment: Yes, if you can invent a little strumming pattern with mainly C, but some Eb, that should imply a C minor chord, because you have the root note and the minor third to give the 'chord' its character.

Comment: For *Creep*, especially try throwing in an A in the mix with the C and Eb for the extra-creepy Dorian sharp sixth flavor.

Comment: If I just strummed the E-flat to imply the c minor chord, would it be like playing the c minor in its first in it's first inversion?

Comment: @luserdroog *Dorian natural sixth flavor

Comment: @cliffordansel not if you only play E-flat, because the idea of chord inversions assumes that all notes of the chord are being played.